# `forall {..}` in GHC 9

Tags: haskell, syntax, forall

This is valid syntax in GHC 9. What do the `{..}` mean (as distinct from `(..)` which GHC 8.10 requires here)?

```hs
ign :: forall {f :: Type -> Type} {p}. Applicative f => p -> f ()
ign _ = pure ()
```

Comment: It looks like it's an inferred type variable that can not be applied using `ign @MyF @MyP`: https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/type_applications.html?highlight=typeapplications#manually-defining-inferred-variables

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [*6.4.14.1. Inferred vs. specified type variables*](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/type_applications.html#inferred-vs-specified-type-variables):

> Since the 9.0.1 release, GHC permits labelling the user-written type or kind variables as **inferred**, in contrast to the default of **specified**. By writing the type variable binder in braces as `{tyvar}` or `{tyvar :: kind}`, the new variable will be classified as **inferred**, not **specified**.

- `..` is a **specified** type
- `{..}` is an **inferred** type

`forall a.` and `forall {a}.` are invisible quantifiers that GHC will instantiate automatically by unification.

```hs
const :: forall a b. a -> b -> a
const a _ = a
```

This means `const True EQ` instantiates *a* (`@Bool`) and *b* (`@Ordering`) without the users help.

If the user wants to explicitly instantiate them they can "override their visibility", using visible type applications. That's why they are **specified** types. (although "specifi**able**" might be a more accurate terminology)

```hs
>> :set -XTypeApplications
>> :t const @Bool @Ordering True EQ
const @Bool @Ordering True EQ :: Bool
```

If for some reason we only want to specify *b* (without summoning the "snail squad": `@_`, umm "[partial type signatures](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/partial_type_signatures.html#partial-type-signatures)") we can make *a* an inferred type. Then the first type is dropped

```hs
const2 :: forall {a} b. a -> b -> a
const2 a _ = a

>> :t const2 @Ordering True EQ
const2 @Ordering True EQ :: Bool
```

For your example it means ghc must infer the type of *f* and *p*. You cannot write `ign @IO @Int`.

---

This becomes more useful when you have kind polymorphism. If you define

```hs
-- MkApply @Type @[] @Int :: [Int] -> Apply @Type [] Int
-- MkApply @_    @[] @Int :: [Int] -> Apply @Type [] Int
type    Apply :: forall (k :: Type). (k -> Type) -> (k -> Type)
newtype Apply f a where
  MkApply :: forall (k :: Type) (f :: k -> Type) (a :: k). f a -> Apply @k f a
```

you must specify the kind *k* when instantiating `MkApply @Type @[] @Int` but this kind is implied by both `[]` and `Int`. You might prefer marking *k* as inferred in `MkApply` so you can write `MkApply @[] @Int`

```hs
-- MkApply @[] @Int :: [Int] -> Apply @Type [] Int
type    Apply :: forall (k :: Type). (k -> Type) -> (k -> Type)
newtype Apply f a where
  MkApply :: forall {k :: Type} (f :: k -> Type) (a :: k). f a -> Apply @k f a
```

Comment: Broadly speaking, I think kind variables should be inferred when possible. This is the opposite of the default, which is unfortunate. For example, `GHC.Generics.Generic1` takes a specified kind argument, so `to1` and `from1` do as well. Horrible user experience.

Comment: I agree with that, it blocked me from making `Category` kind polymorphic with a specified kind (`type Category :: forall ob. Cat ob -> Constraint`). This would have changed the quantification of *ob* in the methods from inferred to specified so you had to write `id @Type @(->) @Int :: Int -> Int`. There was no way to specify *{ob}* as inferred in the methods if it is specified in the kind. I don't like this state of affairs, when I added `Generically1` I had to use GADT syntax and quantify all the variables in the `Generically1 :: forall {k} f a. f a -> Generically1 @k f a` constructor as well

Comment: I'm not sure it's unreasonable for the class specification to match the method specification. I do think it's unreasonable to have to write `from1 @_ @Identity` or whatever

Comment: I'm not sure what the best default is but there was no way to override it for the methods! I don't know if this has changed; there was a proposal for a top-level method signature where you could write `id :: forall {ob :: Type} (cat :: Cat ob) (a :: ob) :: Category @ob cat => cat a a`. I don't like duplicating the signature outside of the class declaration but at least it allows finetuning it!

Comment: Ah, now I understand you. You want to specify an uninferable kind argument for the class, but avoid specifying that same, now inferable, argument to the method. Makes sense.

Comment: Yes and a similar thing might happen with visibility (in the future). `sizeOf :: forall a. Sizeable a => a -> Int` doesn't actually use the `a` argument so it can be supplied with `sizeOf (undefined :: A)`. If the argument is removed we can specify it with type application `sizeOf :: forall a. Sizeable a => Int` but it makes more sense to use visible quantification: `forall a -> Sizeable a => Int`. But even with `forall->` how would you visibly quantify over a method? The type argument of a class is already implicitly quantified outside of the scope of a method. Idk.

Comment: It makes me wonder if `forall {a} -> ..` would be allowed? Presumably not